# SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE vs SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED : generated less parameters on request

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I use SOAPUI and generate java classes with JAX-WS import.

I have an interface like this

```
@WebService(name = "test", targetNamespace = "http://lang.java")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface Test{

@WebMethod(action = "https://...action")
@WebResult(name = "getBean", targetNamespace = "http://...getBean", partName = "getBean")
public Bean test(
@WebParam(name = "parameter1", targetNamespace = "http://lang.java", partName = "parameter1")
String parameter1,
@WebParam(name = "parameter2", targetNamespace = "http://lang.java", partName = "parameter2")
String parameter2,
@WebParam(name = "parameter3", targetNamespace = "http://lang.java", partName = "parameter3")
String parameter3,
@WebParam(name = "parameter4", targetNamespace = "http://lang.java", partName = "parameter4")
long parameter4);
}
```

If I use SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED the body message generated is

```
<S:Body>
<ns2:test xmlns:ns2="http://lang.java" xmlns:ns3="http://...getBean">
<ns2:parameter1>1</ns2:parameter1>
<ns2:parameter2>2</ns2:parameter2>
<ns2:parameter3>a</ns2:parameter3>
<ns2:parameter4>1</ns2:parameter4>
</ns2:test>
</S:Body>
```

If I use SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE the body message generated is

```
<S:Body>
<ns2:parameter1 xmlns:ns2="http://lang.java" xmlns:ns3="http://...getBean">1</ns2:parameter1>
</S:Body>
```

Why is the diference? Why in Bare option it only generates the first parameter? I need that Bare option create all parameters

Answer (score 0):

Its ok! I find the answer here http://www.javajee.com/soap-binding-style-encoding-and-wrapping

Bare option only can use one parameter. When we use Bare, the message request must have zero or one element into Body. The solution is make an object with all parameters we want , and send this object to the method.